# Laravel 4 Fluent Query Builder - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, query-builder

Actually I want to use below query:

```
Select userid,username from users where userid not in (Select distinct fkuserid from staff);
```

So for that I have used:

```
$result=DB::table('users') -> whereNOTIN('userid',DB::table('staff') -> distinct() -> get(array('fkuserid'))) -> get();
```

but it is giving error of Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

Comment: You must pass an array of ids as second parameter in whereNotIn, like `array(1,2,3)`. Now you're passing an array of obejcts - that's what query builder returns by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on L3, which lacks what I've now found in L4 docs. Try:

```
$result=DB::table('users') -> whereNotIn('userid',DB::table('staff') -> distinct() -> lists('fkuserid')) -> get();
```

The `lists()` method should (I think) return only an array of ids as I wrote in comment.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :) You can mark this answer as accepted if you like. Also, I'm editing questions name to be more specific